# PySide / PyQt detect if user trying to close window

Tags: python, pyqt, tkinter, pyqt4, pyside

is there a way to detect if user trying to close window?
For example, in Tkinter we can do something like this:

```
def exit_dialog():
    #do stuff
    pass

root = Tk()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", exit_dialog)
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Override the [**`closeEvent`**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#closeEvent) method of `QWidget` in your main window.

For example:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget): # or QMainWindow
    ...

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # do stuff
        if can_exit:
            event.accept() # let the window close
        else:
            event.ignore()
```

Another possibility is to use the `QApplication`'s [**`aboutToQuit`**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) signal like this:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.aboutToQuit.connect(myExitHandler) # myExitHandler is a callable
```

Comment: Note that this will not work in the main thread is busy calculating. One should move the calculations to another thread to be able to close the window.

Comment: note that on a QMainWindow, there is no attribute `canExit`

Comment: @Tcll, there is no attribute anywhere in the Qt library (to my knowledge, but definitely not in QWidget or QMainWindow).

That is the point: you define it as a custom handler.

Comment: Is it possible to connect `aboutToQuit` from inside a separate file that only subclasses the MainWindow, as is the standard workflow using Qt Designer to define the .ui, pyside-uic to convert that to a .py that you don't manually edit, then this separate file for user implementation of the UI elements?

Answer (score 7):

If you just have one window (i.e the last window) you want to detect then you can use the `setQuitOnLastWindowClosed` static function and the `lastWindowClosed` signal.

```
from PySide2 import QtGui
import sys


def keep_alive():
    print("ah..ah..ah..ah...staying alive...staying alive")
    window.setVisibility(QtGui.QWindow.Minimized)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication()
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
    app.lastWindowClosed.connect(keep_alive)

    window = QtGui.QWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hope that helps someone, it worked for me as on my first attempt I couldn't override closeEvent(), lack of experience!

Comment: Good song in your print)